# Unicode (Bengali-unijoy(m17n) problem

Tags: keyboard, unicode

I am using Linux Mint 18 Sarah. I need to install Bengali keyboard to write. I have installed it labeled `Bengali-unijoy(m17n)`. Now I can write Bengali only under LibreOffice programs. While I'm writing anywhere else, I is being written into normal English. But I want to use Bengali keyboard everywhere such as web page, any other text editor.

My question is: where is wrong and how to solve?

Comment: What program exactly did you use to install `Bengali-unijoy(m17n)`? System wide keyboard settings under X can be done e.g. with `setxkbmap`, `xmodmap`, or `xorg.conf` entries. Search this site for related answers.

Comment: Into the terminal, I  typed `sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n m17n-db m17n-contrib ibus-gtk` and after successful the job, I typed `ibus-daemon -xdr` to run the ibus daemon to appear keyboard setting. I selected Bengali-unijoy .

Comment: So you are using the `ibus` input method, which means it will only work under applications that support this input method. For some ways to set up a Bengali keyboard with `setxkbmap`, see e.g. [here](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Keyboard_layouts#Bengali_.28Bangladesh.29_bd), or google.